# Remove Install New Software from help menu (p2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, product, equinox, p2

I have a question for a RCP project in Eclipse where is installed p2.

I have the help menu with "install new software" and "check for updates" options and I have to remove the "install new software" option from the product.

Can I do that? And if so, how?

I tried to look for an answer in the web but I didn't find anything.

Features that I have in the project are:

1. org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature
2. org.eclipse.rcp
3. org.test (my feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple.
If you insert the help menu by code in ApplicationActionBarAdvisor, p2 fills the menu automatically.
To create a custom help menu without p2 intromissions you must go in plugin.xml, in the extensions tab and add into the menu extension a menu 'Help' and also add to it the command 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.update'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Equinox Transforms](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms) extension (an Adapter Hook) to remove that entry. If you use the xslt-transformation to wipe out that entry you can use the following xsl-snippet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="menuContribution[@locationURI='menu:help?after=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.update']">
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```